# Convert nested map fields to snake case

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-data-mongodb

how to convert all the nested fields of the following object rendered as json to snake_case? Given it's read as a `org.bson.Document`, jackson object mapper won't work as it's designed for POJOs and it's not possible to have POJOs here as the records are schema-less

```
{
   "project_data":[
      {
         "color":"#ffcd03",
         "boardId":"30022"
      },
      {
         "color":"#ffcd03",
         "boardId":"1559427"
      }
   ],
   "type":"Standard",
   "enterprise_id":"30000",
   "version":"10",
   "card_type_id":"30017",
   "owner_type":"Org",
   "timestamp":"1640901794509"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be easily done by adding a custom key serializer to `SimpleModule`, then register it to `ObjectMapper` as follows:

Create a class `SnakeCaseSerializer` which extends `JsonSerializer` to override `serialize()` to modify the key from **lower camel case** to **lower underscore case** (aka snake case) with Google Guava library - [CaseFormat](https://guava.dev/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CaseFormat.html).

```java
public class SnakeCaseSerializer extends JsonSerializer<String> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(String s, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        String fieldNameNew = CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE, s);
        jsonGenerator.writeFieldName(fieldNameNew);
    }
}
```

Add this class into `SimpleModule` as custom key serializer, then register the module to your `ObjectMapper`. (This way is going to change **ALL** the field names, but it doesn't matter because the field names belong to first level are already in snake case.)

```java
SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
simpleModule.addKeySerializer(String.class, new SnakeCaseSerializer());

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(simpleModule);

System.out.println(objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
        .writeValueAsString(objectMapper.readValue(jsonStr, Object.class)));
```

Console output:

```json
{
  "project_data" : [ {
    "color" : "#ffcd03",
    "board_id" : "30022"
  }, {
    "color" : "#ffcd03",
    "board_id" : "1559427"
  } ],
  "type" : "Standard",
  "enterprise_id" : "30000",
  "version" : "10",
  "card_type_id" : "30017",
  "owner_type" : "Org",
  "timestamp" : "1640901794509"
}
```